# Identificacion Submenu (Grupo e hijo) seleccionado en un Navigation Drawer en Android

Tags: java, android, menú

Recientemente he estado trabajando con Android por lo tanto aun soy un novato en cuanto a este se refiere.
Quise hacer una pequenia aplicacion con un Navegation Drawer tomando como ejemplo el siguiente proyecto: https://github.com/sunil676/NavigationViewAndroid

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona muy bien y todo, pero como podran observar los dos submenus que se encuentran son exactamente iguales (Lo cual quita el sentido de uno de ellos), por lo tanto me decidi a hacerlos diferentes.

Para ello basta con editar la clase `Constant` y agregar otro arreglo con los otros submenus. En este caso "subName2"

```
public class Constant {
public static String [] name = {"Android", "iOS"};
public static String [] subName = {"google", "Motorola", "Samsung", "Lenevo"};
public static String [] subName2 = {"Alan", "Chris", "Pepe"};
```

}

El codigo para separlos es 2 menus distintos es el siguiente:

```
private List<TitleMenu> getList()
{
    List<TitleMenu> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        List<SubTitle> subTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < subNames.length; j++)
            {
                SubTitle subTitle = new SubTitle(subNames[j]);
                subTitles.add(subTitle);
            }
        }

        if (i == 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < subNames2.length; j++)
            {
                SubTitle subTitle = new SubTitle(subNames2[j]);
                subTitles.add(subTitle);
            }
        }
        TitleMenu model = new TitleMenu(names[i], subTitles, null);
        list.add(model);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Con esta serie de IF's, se pueden separar en los 2 menus distitnos. Hasta aqui todo muy bien, pero el problema ocurre cuando quiero seleccionar uno de ellos. En ambos casos me toma en cuenta solo el arreglo SubName[].

Que ocaciona esto?
Ocaciona que si por ejemplo, selecciono "Alan" en el menu de iOS se ejecute la accion de "google" en el Menu de Android. Esto es por que toma el "Child" segun su posicionamiento y por que en esa clase se compara con el arreglo subName y no SubName2 (que es el que se encuentra Alan)

[Captura donde se muestran los subMenus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcjI2.png)

Les dejo el codigo del metodo onChildClick:

```
 public void onChildClick(int position)
{
    String name = subNames[position];

    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    fragment.setTitle(name);
}
```

Sabiendo todo esto, **como puedo hacer para saber que Menu estoy seleccionando?
Es decir, como saber si selecciono una opcion de iOS o de Android**. O en su defecto como puedo saber que subMenu selecciono especificamente.
Sabiendo esto, ya puedo colocar una serie de IF's en la clase `onChildClick` para que asi acceda a el arreglo correspondiente. Y que ejecute la accion debida para cada subMenu.

Muchas Gracias, espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Hola Alan, te recomiendo agregar las imágenes en la pregunta en lugar de los enlaces a las imágenes, saludos.

Comment: No me deja agregarlos directamente en la publicacion, no aun.

Comment: Agrega también los segmentos de código en la pregunta no como imagenes. @AlanOliver

Comment: Ya agregue los fragmentos de codigo que mostraba en las imagenes

Comment: muchas gracias Alan, he agregado una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad el ejemplo que indicas no lo considero correcto para la construcción del menú que deseas realizar, me parece que la opción debería ser usar un `ExpandableListView` dentro del `Navigation Drawer`.

Si deseas usar el mismo ejemplo, entonces te puedo comentar que tu clase `MainActivity` implementa `RecyclerAdapter.ItemClickChild`, por lo tanto mediante el método `onChildClick()` únicamente puedes obtener el indice del elemento hijo pero no el del grupo que lo contiene.

```
 @Override
    public void onChildClick(int position) {
        String name = subNames[position];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nombre: " + name + " ,position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        fragment.setTitle(name);
    }
```

Para obtener el grupo debes de modificar la interfaz para que también se envié el grupo, esto se realizaría dentro de la clase `RecyclerAdapter`, realiza las siguientes modificaciones en los métodos:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(final SubTitleViewHolder holder, final int flatPosition,
                                      final ExpandableGroup group, final int childIndex) {

        final SubTitle subTitle = ((TitleMenu) group).getItems().get(childIndex);
        holder.setSubTitletName(subTitle.getName());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //*Determina el grupo.
                int grupo;
                if(group.getTitle().equals(Constant.name[0])){
                    grupo = 0;
                }else{
                    grupo = 1;
                }
                mListener.onChildClick(grupo, childIndex); //* Agrega grupo.
            }
        });
    }

  public interface ItemClickChild{
        //* Agrega grupo.
        void onChildClick(int group, int position); 
    }
```

y  de esta forma obtener tanto el indice del grupo como el indice del elemento hijo del grupo:

```
@Override
public void onChildClick(int group, int position) {
    String name = subNames[position];
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nombre: " + name + " , Grupo " + group + " ,position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    fragment.setTitle(name);
}
```

---

Te sugiero realizar la implementación de `Navigation Drawer` con `ExpandableListView` para fácilmente obtener el indice del grupo y el elemento hijo, este es un [ejemplo](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Navigation-Drawer).

De esta forma puedes obtener sin problema los valores dentro del método `onChildClick()` del `ExpandableListView`.

```
   expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group:  " + groupPosition + "Child Element: " + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Me ayudo al 100%.** Con respecto a tu sugerencia... Cual es mas eficiente? Es que tendre alrededor de 30 Menus y cada menu como con 4 submenus. Y por la imagen de tu sugerencia quiero pensar que todos los submenus son visibles en todo momento, lo cual puede hacer que funcione lento, no?

Comment: Excelente Alan, por escalabilidad prefiero usar el ExpandableListView, nativamente maneja grupos e hijos de grupos, saludos!

Comment: Con el ejemplo que publique probe como con 15 Menus, y funcionaba muy bien.